# How can I avoid "database is locked" sqlite3 errors in django?

Tags: django, multithreading, python-3.x, sqlite

Django version 1.11, sqlite3 version 3.11.

I'm using WAL mode and a long timeout:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db.backends.signals import connection_created


class SQLite3Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'sqlite3_config'

    def ready(self):
        connection_created.connect(configure_sqlite)


# noinspection PyUnusedLocal
def configure_sqlite(sender, connection, **_):
    if connection.vendor == 'sqlite':
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;')
        cursor.execute('PRAGMA busy_timeout=5000;')
```

I want to retain sqlite3 and not move to mysql or postgres because the application is small and is installed by users on multiple servers.

I believe WAL should allow "concurrent" writes by serializing them. The "Database is locked" problem was observed when small bursts (half a dozen or so) were received together.

I can reproduce the problem in the shell with threads. The django model method simply sets a flag and saves the model:

```
def activate(self):
    self.activate = True
    self.save()
```

When I use threads I find it fails if I launch a few threads that attempt it at the same time. There is no wait so the timeout is not involved. The error occurs before the 5 second busy timeout has elapsed (in less than two seconds):

```
In [2]: [NGThread(notifier_group.id).start() for notifier_group in NotifierGroup.objects.all()[:2]]
Out[2]: [None, None]

In [3]: [NGThread(notifier_group.id).start() for notifier_group in NotifierGroup.objects.all()[:3]]
Out[3]: [None, None, None]

In [4]: [NGThread(notifier_group.id).start() for notifier_group in NotifierGroup.objects.all()[:4]]
Out[4]: [None, None, None, None]

In [5]: Exception in thread Thread-97:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/paul/wk/cliosoft/sosadmin/scratch.py", line 41, in run
    toggle_active(notifier_group)
  File "/home/paul/wk/cliosoft/sosadmin/scratch.py", line 30, in toggle_active
    model.activate()
  File "/home/paul/wk/cliosoft/sosadmin/notifications/models/notifier_group.py", line 67, in activate
    self.save()
  File "/home/paul/wk/cliosoft/sosadmin/notifications/models/notifier_group.py", line 33, in save
    self.verify()
  File "/home/paul/wk/cliosoft/sosadmin/notifications/models/notifier_group.py", line 46, in verify
    self.create_notifier(base_spec, model_set, group_event_condition)
  File "/home/paul/wk/cliosoft/sosadmin/notifications/models/notifier_group.py", line 57, in create_notifier
    notifier.users = self.users.all()
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 534, in __set__
    manager.set(value)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 1004, in set
    self.add(*new_objs)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 931, in add
    self._add_items(self.source_field_name, self.target_field_name, *objs)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 1100, in _add_is
    for obj_id in new_ids
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 442, in bulk_create
    ids = self._batched_insert(objs_without_pk, fields, batch_size)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1083, in _batched_insert
    self._insert(item, fields=fields, using=self.db)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1060, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1099, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: database is locked

Exception in thread Thread-98:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/paul/wk/cliosoft/sosadmin/scratch.py", line 41, in run
    toggle_active(notifier_group)
  File "/home/paul/wk/cliosoft/sosadmin/scratch.py", line 28, in toggle_active
    model.deactivate()
  File "/home/paul/wk/cliosoft/sosadmin/notifications/models/notifier_group.py", line 72, in deactivate
    self.save()
  File "/home/paul/wk/cliosoft/sosadmin/notifications/models/notifier_group.py", line 33, in save
    self.verify()
  File "/home/paul/wk/cliosoft/sosadmin/notifications/models/notifier_group.py", line 46, in verify
    self.create_notifier(base_spec, model_set, group_event_condition)
  File "/home/paul/wk/cliosoft/sosadmin/notifications/models/notifier_group.py", line 57, in create_notifier
    notifier.users = self.users.all()
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 534, in __set__
    manager.set(value)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 1004, in set
    self.add(*new_objs)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 931, in add
    self._add_items(self.source_field_name, self.target_field_name, *objs)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 1100, in _add_is
    for obj_id in new_ids
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 442, in bulk_create
    ids = self._batched_insert(objs_without_pk, fields, batch_size)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1083, in _batched_insert
    self._insert(item, fields=fields, using=self.db)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1060, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1099, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/sosadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: database is locked
```

Comment: IHMO, I think you're trying to use sqlite3 well outside it's design scope, even with some scheduling middleware.  According to sqlite3 docs, there can be only 1 writer at a time, and that activity also stalls Shared (read) access.   I get why you're disinterested in using a "fatter" full-feature database, but I think sqlite3 is best used in small embedded systems or apps that are not sharing the file with anything else (basically single user access).    ref:  https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html   I should note that I use sqlite3 databases almost daily on a STRAUX receiver.

Comment: You may be right but with WAL in sqlite3 and the fact that this application is read lots, write rarely (admittedly often in small bursts) makes me think sqlite3 *should* handle it fine. My reading of the documentation implies that if this error were really sqlite3 hitting the write limitations, I should be seeing the timeout elapse and I'm not seeing that.

Comment: If you are using this in tests, this might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51750516/2015768

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the system has scaled, this error has re-occurred. I'm required to use sqlite3 for reasons outside the scope of this problem.

The timeout option in Django seems to be ignored. I tried implementing it myself at the db cursor level with a wrapper around sqlite and had the same problem (at that level you can't back out far enough to abandon the transaction and try a new connection).

I'd have liked a context manager e.g. `with db_locked_retries():...` but it is not possible to iterate within the with context so I created a db_retry function thus:

```
import time
import logging
import random

from django.conf import settings
import django.db

logger = logging.getLogger('django.db.backends')


def db_retry(fn, timeout=None):
    """Call fn with no arguments. If OperationalError exception, make retries until timeout has passed"""
    timeout = timeout or settings.DATABASES['default'].get('OPTIONS', dict()).get('timeout', 5)
    now = time.time()
    give_up_time = now + timeout
    retries = 0
    while now < give_up_time:
        now = time.time()
        try:
            result = fn()
            if retries:
                logger.warning(f'db_retry: Succeeded after {retries} retries')
            return result
        except django.db.OperationalError as exception:
            msg = str(exception)
            if 'locked' in msg:  # pragma: no cover
                retries += 1
                wait_time = random.uniform(1, timeout / 10)
                logger.warning(f'db_retry: {msg}: Retrying after {wait_time} seconds')
                django.db.close_old_connections()
                time.sleep(wait_time)
            else:  # pragma: no cover
                logger.exception(f'db_retry: {msg}: Giving up')
                raise
```

As it is very easy to define the function to pass to this function within the model methods etc. this addresses the problem and successfully uses the timeout to retry the access. This is currently handling some hundreds of concurrent uses and  retries once every thirty minutes or so in my particular use case.

I've only needed to 'wrap' model code that potentially makes several writes so far.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything in the release notes but I've upgraded to Django 2.0 and this problem has now disappeared. With the WAL set up in sqlite3 its all working very well now.

Comment: Interesting.  Good to know.